# Kafka uncommitted message not getting consumed again

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I am processing kafka messages and inserting into kudu table using spark streaming with manual offset commit here is my code.

```
val topicsSet = topics.split(",").toSet
val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG -> brokers,
  ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG -> groupId,
  ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG -> (false: java.lang.Boolean),
  ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG -> "earliest" //"latest" //"earliest"
 )
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
                        ssc,
                        PreferConsistent,
                        Subscribe[String, String](topicsSet, kafkaParams)
                       )
stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
var offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
//offsetRanges.foreach(println)
var msgOffsetsRdd = rdd.map(msg =>{
val msgOffset = OffsetRange(msg.topic(), msg.partition(),  msg.offset(), msg.offset()+1)
        println(msg)
        msgOffset 
      }
    )
   val msgOffsets = msgOffsetsRdd.collect() //here idea was to get only processed messages offsets for commit
   stream.asInstanceOf[CanCommitOffsets].commitAsync(msgOffsets)
}
```

Let us table this example  While inserting data into kudu  I got the error I need to process those messages again, if I stop the job and start it again I am able to get uncommitted message can't we get all uncommitted messages in the streaming?

Answer (score 0):

You have the message, why don't to put a retry logic in case of failure. 
Kafka will give you the same message when you reconnect in case your consumer crashes, Not sure if Kafka will give the same message while the connection is still open.

You can have some retry logic in your code if the failure is due to unavailability of destination datastore , Or if insert the failed due incorrect message format, you can save those messages into a temporary cache, datastore or another kafka topic to retry later or examine whats wrong with those messages.

Comment: I thought this solution but the problem is in my streaming I am getting ~20 messages per second, let us kudu was down by 2 hours in my driver ~ 144000 messages will be in my driver memory it might get crash my streaming job

The second solutions seem to be a workaround

if I could get kafka consumer object from spark streaming I can seek after some time

Comment: Are you consuming messages in a single thread or multiple threads? if it is a single thread, then you can wait for kudu to be up before pulling more messages. If it is multiple thread then you should have an upper limit on the number threads you will create for consuming messages, and block those threads when kudu goes down. To summarize, you need to stop reading messages when kudu is down

Comment: I like this solution can you have a sample to code to set the upper limit and stop reading messages? this could solve my issue thanks a lot Pharaoh

any pointers also help's me

Comment: You can read about ThreadPools, you can use thread pools to maintain threads that would consume messages

Comment: If this answers you question, please mark it as the Answer, Thanks.