# apache kafka consumer resume behaviour

Tags: go, apache-kafka

I am currently working on Apache Kafka using go/golang confluent library. I have some doubts regarding consumer and its APIs.

1. I am using pause and resume APIs of the library and doing manual commits. Let's say, I send 100 messages and without committing, I paused consumer and resume it afterward. I notice it didn't consume those 100 messages again but it started consuming the latest messages. Is this an expected behavior? If yes, is there a way to consume those 100 messages again.
2. When I am resuming the consumers, after some processing, I am doing manual commit. I noticed the return offset committed is -1001 for a partition. I am not able to understand why it is happening and what it means? Did I lose all the data or the commit failed?
3. Can someone please explain to me auto.offset.reset - latest and earliest?

Thanks

Comment: I have actually answered a question similar to this here : [Kafka uncommitted message not getting consumed again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55383558/kafka-uncommitted-message-not-getting-consumed-again/55386024#55386024)

Comment: Also another thing for you to check is are you using a consumer group while starting a new consumer, because the  data that is read and unread is usually tracked by kafka using consumer groups